# for loop works in console but not ran as a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
  echo $(basename $files)
done
```

Works when its copy/inserted into the console, but when ran as a shell script, it returns

```
'/TEST.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'/TEST.sh: line 1: `for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
```

EDIT:

Attempt 2 with #!/bin/sh added to the first line now results

```
-bash: /oper/text2pdf_TEST.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However /bin/sh does exist

Attempt 3 with #!/bin/bash added to the first line now results

```
-bash: /oper/text2pdf_TEST.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However /bin/bash does exist

Comment: (after answering): +1 for including the exact verbatim error which is the only way this question could possibly be answered correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is the big hint:  Notice that it wants to say

```
...near unexpected token `do'
```

but the closing tick is at the beginning of the line.  That's because the token it's printing is `do^M` (`do` followed by a carriage return).

You probably edited the file in a DOS/Windows style editor.  It needs to have UNIX style line endings.

Comment: ... you're probably right. I edited it in editplus on my local machine (windows xp) then moved it to the linux box...

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message says what's wrong:

```
/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

your editor puts an extra character ^M (code 13) after `/bin/sh`. Configure your editor so that it ends lines in the correct way.

It is also possible that you edit the file on an operating system which ends lines with CR+LF and then copy it over to an operating system which uses LF only. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) on some background on this newline confusion.

Comment: This is very common on Cygwin, a Unix-like emulation layer that runs on top of Windows.  The `dos2unix` command will convert a Windows-format text file (with CR-LF line terminators) to the Unix-style format (with LF line terminators) that the shell requires.  Read the man page carefully; unlike most text filter programs, `dos2unix` replaces the file in place.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's right. Including the inplace warning! Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have `dos2unix`, this should work: `tr -d '\r' < Test.sh > tmp ; mv tmp Test.sh ; chmod +x Test.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Without a shebang, your script is executed by `/bin/sh`. Depending on the system, `sh` might not support the `$(...)` syntax.

Add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of the script.

Comment: updated my script with #!/bin/bash in first line, and outputs another error

Comment: That wasn't the problem, but I'll leave this answer here because it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
  echo $(basename $files)
done
```

This one works fine for me. Maybe you forgot the Shebang (The first line specifying the interpreter)?

Comment: updated my script with #!/bin/sh in first line, and outputs another error